# Error when trying to run rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following a youtube tutorial online and I am getting the following error when i try to run my server

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.6 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/
mapper.rb:1565:in `root': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2) (ArgumentError)
```

I tried bundle install and bundle update but im getting the same issue.  I tried deleting the gems that weren't there by default like bourbon, neat and normalize. Still the same issue. Here is a copy of my gemfile.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:     https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
#design
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem "bourbon"
gem "neat"
gem "normalize-rails"

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development


group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger     console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

 # Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: Please can you post your routes.rb file as i think thats where the error is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your `root` in your `routes.rb` is incorrect.

It should be something like this:

`root 'posts#index'`

Comment: No problem :)  Glad to help